# Why has an basic Umbraco site taken over my Azure site as startup site?

Tags: redirect, azure, dns, umbraco, azure-blob-storage

My website at Azure suddenly started showing a basic "Umbraco welcome site" instead of my website hosted on azure. I do not know why, Umbraco is not included in my sourcefiles as far as I know.

When I do http://www.mywebsitename.com it works fine and my azure website gets loaded, but when I dont include 'www'; http://mywebsitename.com - it just shows the "Windows Azure Accelerator for Umbraco" page saying:
"The Windows Azure Accelerator for Umbraco is designed to enable Umbraco applications to be easily run on Windows Azure. The accelerator has been designed to enable you to rapidly deploy Umbraco applications and updates to your application without redeploying a full Windows Azure Service Package. For more information about the accelerator, please visit the CodePlex site located here."

I do not know why this behaviour suddenly happened, how can I get rid of it? I think maybe this behaviour started when I played around with some storage-blobs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your DNS set correctly for the URL without the 'www.' and is your Azure app listening for both www. and the empty subdomain? Sounds to me like the URL without www. is hitting a different application.

Comment: Yes, can you confirm with nsllokup the IPs resolved for www.yourdomain.com and yourdomain.com? As Greg supposed I also guess that would be different IP addresses and only the www. one will point to the Azure service.

Comment: Greg B and astaykov, you're right. I checked the different domains using nslookup and found that the "mywebsitename.com" pointed to a different IP. Was able to solve the problem by using the hints I got from you guys - ThanX!